# boolean doesn't set to true in Java

Tags: java, boolean

Here am trying to change the status of 'stat' which isn't working

```
    public class controller {

        public static void main(String args[]){{

            final AjaxR re = new AjaxR();
            re.setMal("qw");
            if (re.getMal() != null) {
                re.setStat(true);
            }

            if(re.isStat()){
              System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    }



public class AjaxR {

    boolean stat;
    String mal;

    public boolean isStat() {
        return stat;
    }

    public void setStat(final boolean stat) {
        this.stat = stat;
    }

    public String getmal() {
        return mal;
    }

    public void setMal(final String mal) {
        this.mal = mal;

    }
```

Here `re.stat` isn't setting to true. Unless I forcefully execute `re.setStat(true)` manually in debug mode, it is not changing.

Comment: Please provide a complete and reproducible and compilable and well formatted example.

Comment: There are numerous typos in here that prevent the code from compiling. If this is your actual class I'm not surprised it doesn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Um, your edit only introduced even more typos. Please take the time to make sure that your example actually represents your real code, or else you won't get any useful answers. In fact, I strongly suggest you use an IDE like Eclipse, Netbeans or IntelliJ, which catches problems like that for you and tells you how to fix them

Comment: @All, I apologize for the typos. Can you check now?

Comment: @knix2 Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: Works fine here: http://ideone.com/LzPv1H

Comment: @TotZam I still get the error. It isn't printing "Hello"

Comment: You should probably also add "the error" to your question. my guess is that the missing closing braces for both the `AjaxR` class and your `controller` class are a big issue. Also be aware that `public static void main(String args[]){{` has two opening braces for some reason which is yet another typo.

Comment: These are all issues the compiler notifies you of when trying to compile btw, so if it "doesn't work" look at the error it's giving you and see where it's pointing and what it says.

Comment: This is only part of my controller. The same usage works fine in other controllers with final as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple syntactic problems with your code:

- Two opening `{` after your main method header;
- `getMal()` is the wrong case, it doesn't match your method `getmal()` in `AjaxR`;
- There is no closing brace for your `controller` class;
- There is no closing brace for `AjaxR` either.

However, when those errors are fixed (I will leave that as an exercise for you to complete!), your code behaves as you expect - "Hello" is printed and `stat` is definitely set to true.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code into eclipse and was able to easily find the rest of your errors. You did not have the correct amount of opening and closing braces, plus you named you method `getmal()` instead of `getMal()`. All these typos and errors can easily be detected if you use a proper IDE.

After inserting the correct amount of braces and fixing all the typos, the following code works and prints out `Hello`:

```
public class controller {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        final AjaxR re = new AjaxR();
        re.setMal("qw");
        if (re.getMal() != null) {
            re.setStat(true);
        }

        if(re.isStat()){
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    }
}



public class AjaxR {

    boolean stat;
    String mal;

    public boolean isStat() {
        return stat;
    }

    public void setStat(final boolean stat) {
        this.stat = stat;
    }

    public String getMal() {
        return mal;
    }

    public void setMal(final String mal) {
        this.mal = mal;
    }
}
```